# Django - Form not displaying in HTML when receiving an error

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

In my Django project, I display a form when a user sends a GET request.

Here's the code for this:

```
form = SignUpForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
     ....
else:
   return render(request, 'users/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

HTML FOR THIS:

```
 <form method="POST" class="signupform">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for field in form %}
                    <div class="fields">{{ field }}</div>
                    {{ field.errors }}
                    <br>
                {% endfor %}    
                <input class="submitButton" type="submit" value="Sign Up">
 </form>
```

If the user sends a post request, I set `form = SignUpForm(request.POST)` and check if a user with the same username as someone else exists. When this happens, I want to render the whole page again, including the form fields, with an error message displayed.

Here's my current code for this:

```
                    try:
                        user = User.objects.get(username=form.cleaned_data['username'])
                        return render(request, 'users/signup.html', {'error': 'Username field has already been taken', 'form':form})
                    except User.DoesNotExist:
                        ...
```

HTML:

```
{% if error %}
            <form method="POST" class="signupform">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% for field in form %}
                        <div class="fields">{{ field }}</div>
                        {{ field.errors }}
                        <br>
                    {% endfor %}    
                    <input class="submitButton" type="submit" value="Sign Up">
                </form>
                {{ error }}
{% endif %}
```

However when this error occurs, The error message does show but none of the form fields are displayed on the screen. They disappear. Does anybody know the issue? Thank you.

Updated code:

```
context = []
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if not form.cleaned_data['password'] == form.cleaned_data['confirmPassword']:
                context["error"] = 'Username field has already been taken' 
        else:
            raise Http404
else:
    form = SignUpForm()
context['form'] = form
return render(request, 'users/signup.html', context)
```

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the context properly into the template? If the form isn't loading  it means the IF statement is failing so I'd think that the error variable is empty. I usually specify the context in the render function by doing `context = {'error': ....}`

Comment: @JosephRajchwald I am sure, as the IF statement is being called. I know this because in my render, I pass a variable named error with a custom message. And when something goes wrong this error is displayed in the template, but the form fields don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View.py:

```
context = {}
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=form.cleaned_data['username'])
        messages.error(request, 'Username field has already been taken')
        return redirect('users/signup.html')

    except User.DoesNotExist:
         ...
else:
    form = SignUpForm()

context['form'] = form
return render(request, 'users/signup.html', context)
```

template:

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        {{ message }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hello please check my updated code in original post. When implementing that code, I receive the error: **line 18, in signup
    context["form"] = form
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**

Comment: context should be a dictionary, edited code, my apology

Comment: thank you this has worked. One thing is that the password field placeholder remains their and when I type, the characters are written on-top of the placeholder. Do you know the solution?

Comment: Also when the form is refreshed with the error displayed, the inout fields have the previous data in them, and I cannot remove that data/ I can only write over which is not what I want. Do you know how to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry spelling mistake, I meant *input above.

Comment: if you want to re-render the form and pass an error message to the template, consider using [Django's Message Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/messages/). Please see edited answer

Comment: One question I have is that when the form is re-rendered, all the previous data the user entered is lost. How could I re-render the form with the form data the user previously inputted, without encountering the problem of typing over the placeholder or the previous data?